# WPF binding to both view and viewmodel´s properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

This is originally a question about Teleriks TabbedWindow control, but its really a generic.
Question. In a ItemTemplate, how to I bind to *both* the view and properties of the viewmodel

Below, my datasource is a list of Views (ie UserControls). I want to have the View presented in the ContentControl and some properties of the viewmodel presented in the header.

```html
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow x:Class="Porter.Application.Views.MainWindow"
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs2}">
        
    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.TabHeader}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>

</telerik:RadTabbedWindow>
```

**UPDATED RESULT AFTER ANSWER FROM mm8**

```html
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow
     ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs2}" <!--list of ViewModels (lets say ViewModelBase.cs)-->
  ...>

<telerik:RadTabbedWindow.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type acc:SearchAccountsViewModel}">
            <acc:SearchAccountsView/>
        </DataTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hello:HelloWorldViewModel}">
            <hello:HelloWorldView/>
        </DataTemplate>

 </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.Resources>

    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>

</telerik:RadTabbedWindow>
```

Comment: What type is `Tabs2`?

Comment: UswrControl. I dint know any way from VM tp V so I  ound to userControl, hoping to go through .DataContext

Comment: From DataTemplate you have to use RelativeSource if you want to bind to a property of the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tab2` property should return an `IEnumerable<T>` where the type `T` has some public properties that you bind to in the XAML markup.

It may for example have a `TabHeader` property that you bind the header of the tab to in the `ItemTemplate` like this:

```
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow x:Class="Porter.Application.Views.MainWindow"
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs2}">

    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text = "{Binding TabHeader}" />
        </ DataTemplate >
    </ telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>

</telerik:RadTabbedWindow>
```

The `ContentTemplate` should be resolved automatically provided that you have defined a `DataTemplate` for the type `T` in scope of the `RadTabbedWindow`, for example in your `App.xaml`. It's in this template that you add your `UserControl`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourClass}">
    <local:UserControl1 />
</DataTemplate>
```

You should not create a `UserControl` in the view model and add it to `Tabs2`. This breaks what the MVVM pattern is all about, i.e. separation of concerns. A view model doesn't create views.

If you don't have/want an implicit `DataTemplate` in `App.xaml`, you may of course also define the `ContentTemplate` inline:

```
<telerik:RadTabbedWindow x:Class="Porter.Application.Views.MainWindow"
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs2}">

    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabbedWindow.ContentTemplate>

</telerik:RadTabbedWindow>
```

The key point is that you bind to properties of `T` in both templates and that `T` is a POCO and not a control of some kind.

Comment: Ok, seems reasonable. I was hoping to not have to specify each single VM-View, since I want to have have many different controls in my TabbedWondow-control. Im off work now, but I get back to you and mark your anwser as correct whne Ive verified it

Comment: Using an inline `ContentTemplate` without a `TargetType` works for all view model types.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it to work :) . I moved in my templates under resources for the control (RadTabbedWindow). (tiny thing: The property of the DataTempate is "DataType", not "TargetType")

Comment: @Cowborg: Sure. Edited.